# Custom class ostringstream output error

Tags: c++, stringstream

I don't know why this is erroring, but I'm just trying to add something "akin" to endl so that I can throw what's in an ostringstream to our debugger.  I have the following:

```
class debug_stream_info
{
public:
    debug_stream_info(int errorLine, char *errorFile, int level)
        :m_errorLine(errorLine), m_errorFile(errorFile), m_logLevel(level)
    {
    }

    friend std::basic_ostringstream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostringstream<char>& os, debug_stream_info& debug_info);

private:
    int m_errorLine;
    std::string m_errorFile;
    int m_logLevel;

};

std::basic_ostringstream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostringstream<char>& os, debug_stream_info& debug_info)
{
    // Write the stream's contents to cpu_debug
    // Deleted custom logging function.  No errors here though

    // Clear the stream for re-use.
    os.str("");
    os.seekp(0);

    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ostringstream myout;
    myout << "hey there" << " and some more " << "Numbers!!: " << 435 << 54.2 << " that's good for numbers" << debug_stream_info(__LINE__, __FILE__, LOG_LEVEL);

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'debug_stream_info' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` for the line in main.  This is on VS2008.

I'm including sstream, iostream, etc, and have the namespaces set up right.  I'm getting no other errors.  I even tried replacing all occurrances of `basic_ostream` with just `ostringstream` and there was no difference (I'll be having a `w_char` version later, but I wanted the simple case to work first).  I made the object on the line above and then passed a fully-constructed object on the line, and the error was exactly the same.  I've changed the signature of the second argument to and from `const` with no change as well.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: since EVERY response seems to want to put it there, I can NOT use std::ostream because I want this to work ONLY for `std::ostringstream` (and `std::basic_ostringstream`) and not for any type of output stream.  Besides, the function wouldn't compile with ostream anyways, since I'm using the `os.str()` method, which isn't in ostream, only the sub-classes.

Comment: I've never seen someone specifically overload for `std::basic_ostringstream<char>&`. Usually people just overload for `std::ostream&`.

Comment: You're defining a template function for std::basic_ostringstream while your variable is std::ostringstream. Maybe that's causing your template function to not be used?

Comment: As I said in the original post: `I even tried replacing all occurrances of basic_ostream with just ostringstream and there was no difference`.. and I can't used just `ostream` as I only want this overload to work for `ostringstream`, not all `ostream` types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real problem with your code is that you've overloaded `std::ostringstream` rather than `std::ostream`. So your code would work if you write this:

```
debug_stream_info info(/** blah blah**/);

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << info ; //OK
```

However this will not work:

```
oss << 1 << info; //ERROR
```

This is compilation error because the expression `oss<<1` returns an object of type `std::ostream&` which doesn't have overload which takes `debug_stream_info` as second argument. That means if you use cast as:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(oss << 1) << info; //OK
```

then that should work again.

So the solution is to overload `std::ostream`, instead of `std::basic_ostringstream`.

Also, the second parameter should be `const &` . This is also a problem with your code.

So write this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, debug_stream_info const &);
                                                        //^^^^^^^ note this
```

The second parameter should be `const &` so that you could write temporary objects to the stream.

Comment: As said above, I can't use ostream because I dont WANT it to work for all ostreams, only the ostringstream.  And I tried what you put there for const (both in friend statement and implementation), and it's the same error.

Comment: @Kevin: See my updated answer. It explains the real problem with your code.

Comment: @Kevin This solution works for me; just add `const` to your `debug_stream_info` parameter and switch to `std::ostream`. Or as [@CppLearner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386861/478288) says, don't have a temporary object.

Comment: So there's no way to enforce compile-time safety on this thing?  Basically, I do need the methods of ostringstream, which means a cast at run-time.  I'll give you credit though on that you nailed the cause of the error, rather than just "code something else!" like the other answer here is.

Comment: @Kevin: The `static_cast` is not done at runtime. It is done at compile-time(that is why it called `*static*_cast`). So no runtime cost.

Comment: I mean that inside the function itself, as I posted, I'm using the `str()` method of ostringstream.  But obviously any type of ostream could be passed to it, so I'm doing some type of cast.  Now if I wanted to enforce that it's ALWAYS cast prior to use, I may as well enforce "just go to the next line or else you'll get an error."  I wanted something easy-to-use.  Is it impossible?

Comment: @Kevin: Obviously, the purpose of calling `str("")` is to make the stream buffer empty. If that is so, and if you're going to overload `std::ostream` instead, then you can try doing this: `os.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf("", 0);`. Along with it, maybe you need to do something more. Maybe, you need to set the seek position as well.

Answer (score 1):

`debug_stream_info(__LINE__, __FILE__, LOG_LEVEL);` is creating unnamed object which is not returning anything hence error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class debug_stream_info
{
public:
    debug_stream_info(int errorLine, char *errorFile, int level)
        :m_errorLine(errorLine), m_errorFile(errorFile), m_logLevel(level)
    {
    }

    friend std::basic_ostringstream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostringstream<char>& os, debug_stream_info& debug_info);
    std::ostringstream& fun(std::ostringstream& os)
    {
        os<<"Ashish"<<endl;
        return os;
    }
private:
    int m_errorLine;
    std::string m_errorFile;
    int m_logLevel;

};

std::basic_ostringstream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostringstream<char>& os, debug_stream_info& debug_info)
{
    // Write the stream's contents to cpu_debug
    // Deleted custom logging function.  No errors here though

    // Clear the stream for re-use.
//    os.str("");
//    os.seekp(0);

    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::ostringstream myout, test;
        myout << "hey there" << " and some more " << "Numbers!!: " << 435 << 54.2 << " that's good for numbers"
         << debug_stream_info(1, "/home/ashish/test", 1).fun(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually that works fine.  I tried this: `cout << "Try Unnamed: " << std::string("Unnamed!") << endl;` and it works fine.  You can make "temporary" objects like that with no problems.

Comment: @Kevin You can pass a temporary `std::string` to `operator<<()` because it has `const` already, just like [@Nawaz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386778/478288) says.

Comment: This is _not_ the problem, or at least not the only one.  (But you're right that his `operator<<` should take the new type by reference to const, and not reference to non-const.)

Answer (score 1):

Nawaz has explained very clearly why you're getting the error.  The
usual solution in this case is to define your own stream type, unrelated
to `std::istream`.  Something along the lines of:

```
class DebugStream
{
    std::ostringstring* collector;

public:
    template <typename T>
    DebugStream& operator<<( T const& value )
    {
        if ( collector != NULL ) {
            *collector << value;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

There are infinite variations on this; in your case, you could add a
non-template member function for your type; more likely, you'd add a
constructor which took the same arguments:

```
DebugStream( int lineNumber, std::string const& filename, int logLevel )
    : collector( isActive( logLevel ) ? new std::ostringstream : NULL )
{
    //  Initial insertion of lineNumber, filename, timestamp...
}
```

You can also add a destructor which atomically flushes the collected
data to a file (or sends an email, or writes it to the system log, or
whatever).  (Be very careful about this.  You don't want an exception to
escape from the destructor, even if the logging fails.)

Finally, you might want to use a custom streambuf, rather than
`stringstream`.  Say one that keeps the allocated buffer from one
instance to the next.  And if you do this, rather than `new`ing the
stream each time, you might pick up an instance from a table, indexed by
the log level (and initialized from a configuration file).

Comment: A neat idea that I'm giving you reputation from.  I forgot that you can template the `operator<<` to exploit the fact that other classes are already overriding that operator for themselves.  That was the main reason for using ostringstream: to get all the existing overrides.  But I like your idea in general, and that may be the "General solution" for what I'm doing.